# zoom out page to 75% without affecting page layout

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, bootstrap-4, zooming

I want to forced zoom out a web page to 75%. this is site belong to a company website where I work, so I can not share the code. I already try a few of ways that I found in internet including stack overflow. All those ways affecting my page layout. I want the zoom smooth like the browser zoom.

In that page there is carousel. also using bootstrap.
Why I need this zoom? because they asked to do that.

1.

```
window.parent.document.body.style.zoom = 0.75;
```

2.

```
zoom : 0.75; width: extend-to-zoom;
```

3.

```
transform:scale(0.75);
```

4.

```
$('body').css('zoom','80%'); /* Webkit browsers */
$('body').css('zoom','0.8'); /* Other non-webkit browsers */
$('body').css('-moz-transform',scale(0.8, 0.8)); /* Moz-browsers */
```

Comment: `transform: scale(0.75)` shouldn't affect the layout... how does it effect the layout?

Comment: what I know maybe its because there is some image that only show when the viewport is nearby. when scroll up / down a bit far from that image the image will disppear.  Maybe because there are change to the viewport

Comment: Elaborating on why each of your solutions presents to be a problem gives people more insights of what needs to be avoided when thinking of a solution. For example,`transform: scale(0.75)` shouldn't affect layout, but it is not a working solutin for you. As you're not giving away any code, you could probably try to investigate what seems to be the problem of using that solution **and** explicity mention it in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at https://jaukia.github.io/zoomooz/ I think it provides what you are looking for.